# Do I have to resolve ILogger with Castle Windsor?

Tags: castle-windsor, log4net, ioc-container

All of this code is my own libary to be used by my client consumer applications
I have exactly the same installer as in the documentation found [here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-Tutorial-Part-Five-Adding-logging-support.ashx). I also have a bootstrapper pretty much the same as found [here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Installers.ashx), except I use: `_bootStrapContainer = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.Named("MyAssembly"));`

I thought the installer would inject the `Castle.Core.Logging.ILogger` into the `MyLogger` class below but I always get null logger unless I resolve the `MyLogger.Logger` like this:

```
MyLogger lgr = new MyLogger();            
lgr.Logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
```

So my question is do I always have to resolve or am I not doing something correct during 
registration?

```
using Castle.Core.Logging;

public class MyLogger
{
   private ILogger _logger = NullLogger.Instance;

   public ILogger Logger
   {
       get
       {
           return _logger;
       }
       set
       {
           _logger = value;
       }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to register the Windsor logging facility to enable Windsor to resolve the Logger property for you.

Here is an example of setting up the logging facility using [xml](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/06/more-windsor-love-using-log4net.html) and using [code](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Windsor-Tutorial-Part-Five-Adding-logging-support&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Basically it boils down to:

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseLog4Net());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I thought the AddFacility is just another way to register, unless I am mistaken, I also thought windsor would auto resolve my ILogger property to the Core ILogger interface.

Comment: Considering the windsor documentation says this, I just assumed the resolve is done for me, but I have found that I still have to resolve: "How is this used?", you might ask? All you need to do is to ask for a reference to the ILogger interface that resides in the Castle.Core assembly in the Castle.Core.Logging namespace, (common practice is to use a settable property rather than the constructor for that) and you're all set. The container will provide you with a configured and ready to use ILogger instance.

Comment: My understanding of facilities are that a facility extends the existing functionality of the container (http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Facilities.ashx). From reading more about the logging facility (http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Logging-Facility.ashx) the facility allows your class to resolve an implementation of the ILogger interface. The container will not automatically inject the logger instance because of the overhead involved in resolving the properties and injecting the loggers. It is not a core functionality of a container to inject loggers, hence the facility.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it doesn't work because it allready has a value, try again without initializing the field, move that to the get of the property